issue with connecting mongodb through mongoosejs
so I'm using this type of code to connect to mongodb - github link to code
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
cosnt s = "my connection url"
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
        mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
            this.logger.ready('[DB] DATABASE CONNECTED')
        })
        mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
            this.logger.error(`Mongoose connection error: \n ${err.stack}`)
        })
        mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
            this.logger.error('Mongoose disconnected')
        })

        await mongoose.connect(s, {
            connectTimeoutMS: 20000,
            maxIdleTimeMS: 20000,
            useUnifiedTopology: false
        })

error is below
MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at Connection.openUri (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:825:32)
    at C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:414:10
    at C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1288:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:413:20)
    at Comfi.dbs (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\utils\Comfi.js:425:18)
    at new Comfi (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\utils\Comfi.js:63:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\index.js:16:13)

MongooseError: Operation `clients.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:175:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:581:17)
    at process.processTimers (node: internal/timers:519:7)

error on console without using process.on('unhandledRejection') event
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

MongooseError: Operation `clients.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mohit\Documents\My_projects\Comfi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:175:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:581:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Comfi instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:403:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)

Node.js v22.5.0

so the thing is i have added my current ip or even allow anywhere but I'm still getting connection error.
one thing i noticed is that if i add an ip and then start the code, it will work but if i stop and start again then i get above errors. no i'm not adding my ip as temporary or one time and they are still active. image from mongodb section
i even tried to use my actual ip which i get from ipconfig /all under network section - ip4 but no luck
this code is used in my discord,js bot
